# Django DRF: How to adjust the representation of the choice fields

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female"),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GENDER)

class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
```

Now i get

```
{
    "gender": "M",
}
```

I want

```
{
    "gender": "Male",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the [**`get_fieldname_display(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) to retrieve the display value of the choice.

We do this by setting the [**`source=…`** parameter [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) to the `get_gender_display` method:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.CharField(source='get_gender_display')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = '__all__'
```